# create a Custom field Type for sharepoint online/ office 365

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, column, custom, custom-field-types

I need an custom option (custom field type) which can validate input that it is email(just for an example) or not by just selecting column type.
Please look the attachment for more information where I need the column type.
I need option on yellow spot.

requirements for = **SharePoint Online/ Office 365**

[image: custom field type]

Comment: mark my answer if it solved ur problem

Comment: You can't do this in SharePoint Online.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write custom solution for that. take reference from here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-2013-Create-eb30a620

Happy SharePoint'ing

Comment: This won't work for SharePoint Online.

Comment: yes this wont work for sharepoint online. It is for On premises.